# Prevent treemap merging on collision

Tags: java, treemap

Edit: I should have probably mentioned that I am extremely new to Java programming. I just started with the language about two weeks ago.

I have tried looking for an answer to this questions, but so far I haven't found one so that is why I am asking it here.

I writing java code for an Dungeons and Dragons Initiative Tracker and I am using a TreeMap for its ability to sort on entry. I am still very new to java, so I don't know everything that is out there.

My problem is that when I have two of the same keys, the tree merges the values such that one of the values no longer exists. I understand this can be desirable behavior but in my case I cannot have that happen. I was hoping there would be an elegant solution to fix this behavior. So far what I have is this:

```
  TreeMap<Integer,Character> initiativeList = new TreeMap<Integer,Character>(Collections.reverseOrder());
  Character [] cHolder = new Character[3];

  out.println("Thank you for using the Initiative Tracker Project.");

  cHolder[0] = new Character("Fred",2);
  cHolder[1] = new Character("Sam",3,23);
  cHolder[2] = new Character("John",2,23);

  for(int i = 0; i < cHolder.length; ++i)
  {         
     initiativeList.put(cHolder[i].getInitValue(), cHolder[i]);
  }

  out.println("Initiative List: " + initiativeList);
```

Character is a class that I have defined that keeps track of a player's character name and initiative values.

Currently the output is this:

```
Initiative List: {23=John, 3=Fred}
```

I considered using a TreeMap with some sort of subCollection but I would also run into a similar problem. What I really need to do is just find a way to disable the merge. Thank you guys for any help you can give me.

EDIT: In Dungeons and Dragons, a character rolls a 20 sided dice and then added their initiative mod to the result to get their total initiative. Sometimes two players can get the same values. I've thought about having the key formatted like this:

```
Key = InitiativeValue.InitiativeMod
```

So for Sam his key would be *23.3* and John's would be *23.2*. I understand that I would need to change the key type to float instead of int.

However, even with that two players could have the same Initiative Mod and roll the same Initiative Value. In reality this happens more than you might think. So for example,

Say both Peter and Scott join the game. They both have an initiative modifier of 2, and they both roll a 10 on the 20 sided dice. That would make both of their Initiative values 12.

When I put them into the existing map, they both need to show up even though they have the same value.

```
Initiative List: {23=John, 12=Peter, 12=Scott, 3=Fred}
```

I hope that helps to clarify what I am needing.

Comment: What do you *want* to have happen? What problem would you run into with any of several multimap implementations?

Comment: If you want them to be a Set you can't have them with same key. I'll suggest use something unique of the Character class to store as key

Comment: Ditto to Dave, but also show us sample input and desired result for the case that's causing the problem.

Comment: I guess your problem is to identify a real unique identifier for your objects. You should check which is your identifier, in OO you should not have the same identifier for different objects

Comment: If you _really_ want to store multiple values for a single key, you want a [Guava TreeMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html)

Comment: It think you want a simple list sorted on initiaive, then use `Collections.shuffle()` of all characters with the same initiative to pick the one that moves forst

Comment: Why not to do this:
`Initiative List: {23=John, 12={Peter, Scott}, 3={Fred}}`

Comment: gersonZaragocin, I don't understand how to implement what you're suggesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a bunch of characters and their initiatives, and want to "invert" this structure to key by initiative ID, with the value being all characters that have that initiative.  This is perfectly captured by a MultiMap data structure, of which one implementation is the [Guava TreeMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html).

There's nothing magical about this. You could achieve something similar with a

```
TreeMap<Initiative,List<Character>>
```

This is not exactly how a Guava multimap is implemented, but it's the simplest data structure that could support what you need.

If I were doing this I would write my own class that wrapped the above `TreeMap` and provided an `add(K key, V value)` method that handled the duplicate detection and list management according to your specific requirements.

Comment: a) Thinking that a `TreeMultimap` is the same as a `TreeMap<Initiative, List<Character>>` raises a lot of potential for confusion, e.g. on empty lists. b) Even if it were, `TreeMultimap` would be a `TreeMap<Initiative, TreeSet<Character>>`.  You'd want to use `Multimaps.newListMultimap` to get a custom combination of `Map` and value collection implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You say you are "...a `TreeMap` for its ability to sort on entry..." - but maybe you could just use a `TreeSet` instead.  You'll need to implement a suitable `compareTo` method on your `Character` class, that performs the comparison that you want; and I strongly recommend that you implement `hashCode` and `equals` too.

Then, when you iterate through the `TreeSet`, you'll get the `Character` objects in the appropriate order.  Note that `Map` classes are intended for lookup purposes, not for ordering.